# Tree Join in SQL Query

Tags: sql, db2

I have to retrieve all the child's by giving only the parent as input. 
Example I have a table data as

TABLEA

```
LOAN_ID    CLIENT_ID
1          7
1          8
2          7
4          8
4          9
4         10
5          9
5         11
13        2
14        3
```

If I have given only input as CLIENT_ID=7 then the query has to select all the columns from above table except last two column because
client_id 7 has 1,2 LOAN_ID and in 1 the PRSN_ID 8 has loan_id=4  and in this loan prsn_id 9 has again 5 as loan_id.

can we write a sql query for this without stored procedure.

```
with temptbl (LOAN_ID, CLIENT_ID) as
( select 1 LOAN_ID, 7 CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION
  select 1 LOAN_ID, 8 CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION
  select 2 LOAN_ID, 7 CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION 
  select 4 LOAN_ID, 8 CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION
  select 4 LOAN_ID, 9 CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION 
  select 4 LOAN_ID, 10 CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION
  select 5 LOAN_ID, 9 CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION
  select 5 LOAN_ID, 11 CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 ) 
  select * from temptbl;
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: DB2. the sample data query is below.

Comment: with temptbl (LOAN_ID, CLIENT_ID) as (
select 1  LOAN_ID, 7  CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION select 1  LOAN_ID, 8  CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION select 2  LOAN_ID, 7  CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION select 4  LOAN_ID, 8  CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION select 4  LOAN_ID,  9 CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION select 4  LOAN_ID, 10  CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION
select 5  LOAN_ID, 9  CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION select 5  LOAN_ID, 11  CLIENT_ID FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)
select * from temptbl;

Comment: Your problem description does not match the sample table -- where is `PRSN_ID'? Anyway, google for "recursive SQL".

Comment: sorry. PRSN_ID is same as CLIENT_ID.

Comment: Google for writing queries in DB2 SQL using Connect By Clause. That should more or less work for the scenario you have described.

Comment: sure, trying. will post once i got the answer.